# Group data with a generic type list

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have list data (does not know the specified type) and a property name (in string). How do I group list data base on property name?

Comment: Do you know the type of the property? Either in terms of an actual type (`string` etc) or in terms of a `T` ?

Comment: similarly do you half no the list item type, i.e. is the List of List<T> and you simply don't know T at compile time (i.e. your method is generic) or is thie list just an IList?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution will work when the type is fully unknown (i.e. its not just a List within a generic function)

Here is the helper class with the utility function.

```
public static class HelperClass {
  public static object GetProperty(this object source, string name) {
     if (source == null) return null;
     var pi = source.GetType().GetProperty(name);
     if (pi == null) return null;
     return pi.GetValue(source);
  }
}
```

Now assuming that you have your list data in a vaiable called `myList` and the property name is in `name`:

```
var groupedResults = myList.Cast<object>().GroupBy(x => x.GetProperty(name));
```

The Cast() makes sure that you are using an IEnumerable where T is object so that the `GroupBy` extension will work.

If however you are operating with a `List<T>` where the specific `T` is a generic argument (i.e. you don't know that `T` is a `string` but you know that its the generic argument `T` there are alternative solutions that can be built using expressions. This would allow you to use against IQueryables that should translate correctly against your backed sql source.

```
static class HelperClass {

  static Expression<Func<T,object>> GroupByExpression<T>(string propertyName) {
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T),"x");
    var body =  Expression.Property(parameter,propertyName);
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T,object>>(Expression.Convert(body, typeof(object)), parameter);
  }
}
```

This can now be used with both an `IQuerable<T>` and an `IList<T>`

so if you are inside a generic function where `T` matches the `T` in `IList<T>` you can use

where `myList` is `IQueryable<T>`:

```
myList.GroupBy(HelperClass.GroupByExpression<T>(name))
```

and where `myList` is `IList<T>` or `IEnumerable<T>`

```
myList.GroupBy(HelperClass.GroupByExpression<T>(name).Compile())
```